# limiting number of cores with multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have to run the same process about a hundred times with one different argument and I want to run it with `multiprocessing.Process()` on a computer with 16 cores but I only want to use 4 cores (because the computer is shared with other people). I am trying to avoid `multiprocessing.map()` because I have to pass several arguments to the function being called, so I'd have to create tuples and so on. I might also want to communicate between processes and pass arguments in the future so a combination of `Process()` and `Queue()` seems the right choice. So here's a very simple example:

```
import multiprocessing

def run(mass, input_unit, unit):
    if input_unit == 'kg':
        if unit == 'kg':
            return mass
        elif unit == 'g':
            return 1e3 * mass
    elif input_unit == 'g':
        if unit == 'kg':
            return 1e3 * mass
        elif unit == 'g':
            return mass
return

p = []
for i in xrange(100):
    p.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=run, args=(i,'kg','g'), name=i))
    p[i].start()
for pi in p:
    pi.join()
```

(In reality I pass many more arguments to `run()`, so `map()` is not very handy). I've read that the number should be limited by calling

```
queue = multiprocessing.Queue(Nproc)
```

and passing the queue to `Process()`, but this also doesn't seem to work. What is happening is that there are 100 processes being run at the same time (or at least 16 and the rest waiting to run, but all 100 show up in `top`)

Is there a way to tell `Process()` to use no more than `N` cores and start a process immediately after one of them is finished, not having to wait for the other three (which would happen with `p.join()`)?

Thanks!